# Taking average of Dataframe, Object values not printing

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, average

I have a Data frame as follows:

| Date | Time | U | V |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-03 | 10:00:21:08 | 5 | 8 |
| 2023-01-03 | 10:00:25:08 | 2 | 3 |
| 2023-01-03 | 10:00:27:08 | 3 | 3 |
| 2023-01-03 | 10:00:29:08 | 6 | 6 |
| 2023-01-03 | 10:00:31:08 | 4 | 6 |
| 2023-01-03 | 10:00:35:08 | 9 | 7 |
| 2023-01-03 | 10:00:37:08 | 10 | 4 |
| 2023-01-03 | 10:00:39:08 | 11 | 12 |

I am trying to average 2 values and printing the results for the averages of the Date, Time, U and V.

I have done this:

```
data_columns=['Date','Time','U','V']
df3= data.groupby(np.arange(len(data))//2).mean()
print(df3)
```

However, my numeric values average and print, but my Date and Time don't. I know thats because df.groupby function only works on the numeric values and the Date and Time types are objects.
How do I get the date and time to print such that the initial time prints for the averaging value. Like so:

```
Date | Time |U  | V|
2023-01-03 10:00:21:08 3.5 5.5 
2023-01-03 10:00:27:08 4.5 4.5
2023-01-03 10:00:31:08 6.5 6.5
2023-01-03 10:00:37:08 10.5 8
```

`
** in reality its ...np.arrange(len(data)//300).mean()

Comment: What are the data types of the original frame? `data.dtypes`

Comment: @CodeDifferent Date: Object, Time: Object, U: float64, V:float64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, the `groupby()` function uses with a column name or a list of column name like

`groupby('Date')` or `groupby(['Date','Time'])`

**UPDATE**
After discuss with @doctorstrange, I would like to update the answer.
The code below try to create a dummy data:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import time
import random
logfile='log.csv'
c=0

with open(logfile,'a') as handle:
    handle.write('Date,Time,U,V\n')
    while c<=100:
        now=datetime.now()
        D=now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        T=now.strftime('%H:%M:%S:%f')
        u=random.randint(1, 20)
        v=random.randint(1, 20)
        handle.write(f'{D},{T},{u},{v}\n')
        c=c+1
        time.sleep(1)
```

The `data` is the pandas dataframe, like this

|  | Date | Time | U | V |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-01-13 | 11:31:43:481765 | 15 | 8 |
| 1 | 2023-01-13 | 11:31:44:485698 | 13 | 11 |
| 2 | 2023-01-13 | 11:31:45:489411 | 7 | 11 |
| 3 | 2023-01-13 | 11:31:46:492592 | 6 | 11 |
| 4 | 2023-01-13 | 11:31:47:496405 | 18 | 17 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 96 | 2023-01-13 | 11:33:19:812832 | 10 | 5 |
| 97 | 2023-01-13 | 11:33:20:812896 | 5 | 15 |
| 98 | 2023-01-13 | 11:33:21:816767 | 16 | 9 |
| 99 | 2023-01-13 | 11:33:22:818553 | 6 | 8 |
| 100 | 2023-01-13 | 11:33:23:818651 | 13 | 6 |

The data was writen into `logfile`, 'log.csv' file. Read into the dataframe. `data` variable.

```
data=pd.read_csv(logfile)
```

Create a new column `timestamp` by apply the `pd.Timestamp.combine()` which combine `Date` and `Time`.

```
data['timestamp']=data.apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp.combine(
     datetime.strptime(x['Date'],'%Y-%m-%d')
    ,datetime.strptime(x['Time'],'%H:%M:%S:%f').time()
   ), axis=1)
```

You will get this,

|  | Date | Time | U | V | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-01-13 | 11:31:43:481765 | 15 | 8 | 2023-01-13 11:31:43.481765 |
| 1 | 2023-01-13 | 11:31:44:485698 | 13 | 11 | 2023-01-13 11:31:44.485698 |
| 2 | 2023-01-13 | 11:31:45:489411 | 7 | 11 | 2023-01-13 11:31:45.489411 |
| 3 | 2023-01-13 | 11:31:46:492592 | 6 | 11 | 2023-01-13 11:31:46.492592 |
| 4 | 2023-01-13 | 11:31:47:496405 | 18 | 17 | 2023-01-13 11:31:47.496405 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 96 | 2023-01-13 | 11:33:19:812832 | 10 | 5 | 2023-01-13 11:33:19.812832 |
| 97 | 2023-01-13 | 11:33:20:812896 | 5 | 15 | 2023-01-13 11:33:20.812896 |
| 98 | 2023-01-13 | 11:33:21:816767 | 16 | 9 | 2023-01-13 11:33:21.816767 |
| 99 | 2023-01-13 | 11:33:22:818553 | 6 | 8 | 2023-01-13 11:33:22.818553 |
| 100 | 2023-01-13 | 11:33:23:818651 | 13 | 6 | 2023-01-13 11:33:23.818651 |

Then, as you use `df3` variable, the code below use `resample()` function with `rule='min'` (every minute) on the `timestamp` column and set the offset by `0s` (zero second). Then calculate the `mean()` and then reset the dataframe index, set the name of the column to `U_mean`

```
df3=data.resample(rule='min', on='timestamp', offset='0s').U.mean().reset_index(name='U_mean')
df3
```

The first result like this

|  | timestamp | U_mean |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-01-13 11:31:00 | 9.823529 |
| 1 | 2023-01-13 11:32:00 | 10.783333 |
| 2 | 2023-01-13 11:33:00 | 8.250000 |

Lastly, for `df4` for `V` mean

```
df4=data.resample(rule='min', on='timestamp', offset='0s').V.mean().reset_index(name='V_mean')
df4
```

Then merge `df3` and `df4` on `timestamp` you will get the final result

```
pd.merge(df3,df4, on='timestamp')
```

Finally, the result is

|  | timestamp | U_mean | V_mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-01-13 11:31:00 | 9.823529 | 11.117647 |
| 1 | 2023-01-13 11:32:00 | 10.783333 | 10.716667 |
| 2 | 2023-01-13 11:33:00 | 8.250000 | 12.541667 |

Hope this help.

Comment: Where within the code do you specify the number of values being averaged? ie. //2 ?

Comment: it is `groupby().mean()` which will count the number of each group and calculated the mean for you.

Comment: I just realized. the dataframe is time depended, and the Date and Time are object types. So it does go from 10:00:21.08 to 10:00:31.08 and so on.

Comment: @doctorstrange so you can apply the code with your real data and please give back the result. Or if it isn't what you want, please describe more. :-)

Comment: What I am doing with my code is trying to average U and V from an CSV to 15 minute increments, which is 300 rows. So the code takes the average of the first 300 lines, produces the value and then the second and so forth. The issue I run into is, `df3= data.groupby(np.arange(len(data))//300).mean()` only operates on the number (float64 and int64 types) but my Date and Time column is an object type, so it does not operate/ print what the Date and Time are for each average. Like I mentioned above I need it to print the date and time for the start of each 15 min set. Also, Thank you so Much!!!!

Comment: @doctorstrange Hmmmm, let.me update my answer again.

Comment: Thank you so much! you have no idea how much i appreciate it!!